# How to use Marathon JavaDriver on alreday open application

Tags: marathon, marathontesting

I have Swing application running on my machine and want's to do automation of it using JavaDriver.

If I use JavaDriver to launch the application then I'm not seeing any problem, but I have a requirement to run automation on an already launched/running application. I tried to look for the solution, but couldn't find anything on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need launch you application to use Marathon Java driver as Java agent and Connect to it using a JavaProfile or RemoteWebDriver.

```
java -Dmarathon.mode=playing -javaagent:"<PATH_TO_AGENT>/marathon-java-agent-5.x.y.z.jar"=24444  your_app.jar
```

Ref: https://marathontesting.com/javadriver/